# Bootstrap Modal in Django application with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have little problem in my Django application. I am tring to use modal from bootstrap 4 and ajax to create new object. Here below you see code that I used. When user click the button I dont see modal window but background became grey. What I did wrong? Why I dont see modal? Is my ajax correct?

**detail.html:**

```
<!-- BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION -->
<button class="add-group-task" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-group-task-modal" data-url="{% url 'project:group_task_add' project_code=project.code %}">{% trans 'Create' %}</button>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="group-tasks-table">
   <!-- TABLE CONTENT-->
</table>

<!--MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="add-group-task-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-group-task-modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^(?P<project_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/add_new_group_task/$', group_task_add, name='group_task_add'),
```

**view.py:**

```
def group_task_add(request, project_code):
    data = dict()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GroupTaskAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group_task = form.save(commit=False)
            group_task.project = project
            group_task.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            group_tasks = GroupTask.objects.filter(project=project_code)
            data['html_group_tasks'] = render_to_string('project/project_detail.html', {'group_tasks': group_tasks})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = GroupTaskAddForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_group_task_add_form'] = render_to_string('project/group_task_add.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**javascript:**

```
$(function () {
            /* Functions */
            var loadForm = function () {
                var btn = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: btn.attr("data-url"),
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#add-group-task-modal").modal("show");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#add-group-task-modal .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
                    }
                });
            };

            var saveForm = function () {
                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr("action"),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    type: form.attr("method"),
                    dataType: 'json',
                     success: function (data) {
                        if (data.form_is_valid) {
                            $("#group-tasks-table tbody").html(data.html_group_tasks);
                            $("#add-group-task-modal").modal("hide");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#add-group-task-modal .modal-content").html(data.html_group_task_add_form);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            };

            // Create book
            $(".add-group-task").click(loadForm);
            $("#add-group-task-modal").on("submit", ".js-group-task-add-form", saveForm);
        });
```

**group_task_add.html:**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'project:group_task_add' project_code=project.code %}" class="js-group-task-add-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addGroupTaskModalLabel">{% trans 'Create a new group task' %}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupTaskInput">{% trans 'Name' %}</label>
            {{ form.name }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{% trans 'Close' %}</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Create' %}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ERROR:**
[image]

Comment: Are you able to see any JS errors on the console tab when the button is clicked?

Comment: Well in console i have this error when click the button: `TypeError: $.ajax is not a function[Detail]  6ee4fa74-8e91-4365-98be-adb0325ce36c:226:17` In my url I have id which then I use in views.

Comment: There is some syntax issue with your ajax code. And also is jquery.js included in the template?

Comment: Look my post again pls. I added picture with error. In what part of ajax code I did mistake?

Comment: Line number 226 or 17 accd to error.

Comment: Its shows that place `$.ajax({` as error in loadForm function. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try with following html and js code combination:

```
<!-- BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION -->
<button ... onclick="modalHandler()">{% trans 'Create' %}</button>

// js code 
function modalHandler(){
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
                url: btn.attr("data-url"),
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#add-group-task-modal").modal("show");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#add-group-task-modal .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
                }
        });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code raise error: `TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`. I am really comfused now =(